# When to use "onboard the ship" and "on board the ship"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

When do we use "onboard the ship" vs. "on board the ship"?

From https://www.bizjournals.com/baltimore/news/2020/03/09/maryland-confirms-its-sixth-case-of-coronavirus.html:

> All of the people **onboard the ship** will be sent to military bases in Texas and Georgia to be quarantined.

From https://www.nytimes.com/2019/03/23/world/europe/viking-sky-cruise-ship-evacuation.html:

> Nearly 1,400 passengers and crew members **on board the Viking Sky** were being evacuated on Saturday after the ship lost engine power.Credit...

Comment: _Onboard the ship_ is non-standard usage - it is usually written as two words. _On-board_ or _onboard_ can be used as an adjective to describe equipment that is installed in a ship or vehicle, such as an _onboard computer_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"**Onboard**", one word, is wrong.

"On-board" (hyphenated) is an adjective.

"The captain is on-board."

The on-board meals were delicious."

"On board" (not hyphenated) + noun is a prepositional modifier phrase as well as having other functions:

"We ate our dinner on board the yacht."

In both of your examples, the word "***aboard***" would have been much better.

OED

> **a. on board [...] has now, in common use, the meaning: On or in a ship, boat, etc.; into or on to a ship.**

[The] fuller form [was] *on ship-board* (cf. Middle English ‘within schippe burdez’ [where "burdez" = sides]), and the construction ‘on board of the ship’, or ‘on board the ship’ (where ... ‘board’ means 'the deck').

[...]**On board** appears to be a later expansion (...) of ***aboard*** adv. and preposition, and this to have been taken directly from French à bord, ...in which bord = ‘ship's side’ comes contextually to be equal to ‘ship’ itself. ... **On board**, first appears late in the 17th cent.

Comment: Onboard is proper. On-board is not much used in the shipping biz. [On Board or Onboard](https://writingexplained.org/on-board-or-onboard)

Comment: Did you mean that *onboard* was wrong *in that sentence*?

Answer (score 1):

Navy: Use aboard when referencing events taking place on a ship or aircraft. Use onboard when discussing shore based events.